# SET Single_USER Mode SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with setting a database  in Single User Mode, Every time i run below code, But it's taking endless process

```
USE {Database_Name}

ALTER DATABASE {Database_Name} SET SINGLE_USER;
 GO
DBCC CHECKDB({Database_Name},REPAIR_REBUILD)
 GO
ALTER DATABASE {Database_Name} SET MULTI_USER;
 GO
```

Comment: Do you mean the checkdb is taking a long time, or just setting the database to single user is taking ages? (or on setting it, you lose your connection and havn't seen that)

Comment: Single user mode only taking time, after that now i set single user mode via property, then its working fine.

Comment: `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` cancels all running transactions and closes open connections. This tends to speed things up -- at the obvious cost of interrupting whatever else was going on .

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL set the database to `SINGLE_USER` mode to obtain exclusive access. Initially It sets database to `READ_ONLY` and returns access to the database to all users.

The termination option `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` is specified in the first `ALTER DATABASE` statement. This will cause **all incomplete transactions to be rolled back and any other connections to the database to be immediately disconnected**.

Example SQL:

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE DB_Name
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

DBCC CHECKDB('database_name', REPAIR_REBUILD)
GO

ALTER DATABASE DB_Name
SET READ_ONLY;
GO
```

If you want to set Database back to `Multi_suer`, use below SQL:

```
ALTER DATABASE DB_name
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

For more details check this link: [How to set a Database to Single-user Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-2017)